# Java simple complex number class

Tags: java, complex-numbers

```
public String toString() {
    final String IMAGINARY_UNIT = "i";
    
    if (equalsApprox(im , 0)) {
        return String.valueOf(re);
    }
    String sign = "-";
    if (im > 0) {
        sign = "+";
    }
    if(equalsApprox(re, 0)) {
        return "MyComplex" + sign + IMAGINARY_UNIT + Math.abs(im);
    }
    return "MyComplex" + re + " " + sign + IMAGINARY_UNIT + Math.abs(im); 
}

public boolean equalsApprox(MyComplex z) {
    return equalsApprox(re, z.re) && equalsApprox(im, z.im);
}

private static boolean equalsApprox(double x , double y) {
    final double EPSILON = 1E-14;
    return Math.abs(x-y) <= EPSILON * Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
}
```

I want a clear explanation about the part of equalsApprox which I can not understand how it checks and compares with tolerance(I don't know what does tolerance mean in here : please explain me this too) and return the values in different conditions .This is the ending part of the code not all of it. please help me to understand it .

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand it, it gets a little complicated!

Computers aren't magical; there is a limit to how 'large' a number you store can be. For example, `int` can only store between -2147483648 and +2147483647 (try it!). Those numbers aren't arbitrary, it's `2^31` (2 to the power of 31 - `2*2*2*2*...`) for both the positive and negative numbers. Because ints use 32 bits. One bit for the sign, 31 bits for the number.

`double` is similarly restricted. It uses 64 bits, but it's still limited. Only 2^64 different numbers can be stored. (Why? Math - if I give you 3 light switches and the only way you can communicate with me is to toggle them and then leave the room, there's only at most 8 different messages you can send me. That's because `2^3 = 8`. With 64 lightswitches it's `2^64`. That's a lot of numbers, but there are an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1, let alone in all of infinity).

So, given that doubles can only store 2^64 unique numbers, which numbers *can* doubles store? It's as if someone threw 2^64 darts at the number line - those are numbers double can store. Anything else a double **can not** store; if you try to, or the result of a calculation is a value that doesn't have a 'dart', it gets silently rounded to the nearest dart.

The darts aren't thrown arbitrarily; if you imagine the number line, there are as many darts around 0-2 as there are everywhere else - the nearer to 1.0, the more dense the darts are packed. Eventually, above 2^52, there's less than one dart per whole number (with the weird effect that therefore `x+1` can be equal to `x`, for sufficiently large `x`, even! - the result is rounded to the nearest dart which eventually is just `x` again).

This means errors occur, and the larger the number, the higher the error is likely to be. This means that equality is then complicated. Simple example:

```
double x = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) x += 0.1;
double y = 1.0;
System.out.println(x == y); // This prints false!!!
System.out.println(x - y);
```

The difference (the last line) prints `-1.1102230246251565E-16` - so a really tiny difference (E-16 means 10^-16, so, the difference is -0.000000000000000011102230246251565.

But.. 10 * 0.1 **is** 1.0, so why does that print false? Because of that darts thing - rounding killed you. Computers count in binary; while "one tenth" works well in decimal (It's just 0.1), just like "one third" **does not** 'work' in decimal (it's 0.33333333... you can never get it perfect), one tenth is similarly not quite perfect in binary. Hence, yup, 0.1 isn't quite on a dart, and each intermediate value (0.1, 0.2, 0.3) isn't a dart either, so you keep compounding 10 tiny rounding errors.

The solution is, when wanting to consider if 2 double values are 'equal', that you can't just use `==`, you need to define it more as 'are they **really** close to each other?' instead.

Hence this code checks the difference (`Math.abs(x-y)` is just `x-y`, with the sign removed: The difference between x and y, and checks if that is really tiny. How tiny? Well, in basis, EPSILON (so, `1E-14`, which is scientific notation and means the same as -0.00000000000001), except, we scale this a bit (multiply it by *the largest* amongst x and y), because the errors tend to be larger in magnitude when you move away from the 0, because there are fewer and fewer darts as you get further and further away from it.

Applying it to our `0.1*10 vs 1.0` situation:

```java
double x = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) x += 0.1;
double y = 1.0;
System.out.println(x == y); // This prints false!!!
double EPSILON = 1E-14;
System.out.println(Math.abs(x-y) <= EPSILON * Math.max(Math.abs(x),
Math.abs(y)));
```

That last line prints `true`.